# What is the best way to communicate authorization between a client and REST API?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, authorization, roles

I'm developing an application will use AngularJS for the front-end, communicating to a REST service on the backend, implemented as J2EE/Spring.  The back-end services are secured through role-based authorization.

In the front end of the application I would like to have the UI only allow users to perform operations for which they are authorized.  The code should show/hide elements based on the user's permissions.

For example, there is a feature where you can list the users of the system.  You can edit any user's information including their role if you have the admin_users permission.  If you do not, the server will not allow the update operation.  The UI should reflect this by disabling or hiding the edit button also.

What is the best way to communicate the user's authorization from the back end to the front-end?  I could, for example, provide an extra service which returns the current user's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out (Json Web Token) JWT. It will provide a random complicated key (JWT Secret) to make brute forcing the token very hard.

Visit https://jwt.io for more info.

Comment: JWT will allow me to handle the authentication piece, and I plan to use it or something similar like a SAML token.  This question pertains to authorization.  I would like the code on the UI side to know the permissions the current logged in user has so that it can adjust the UI to disable any features the current user does not have permission for.  The server knows these permissions and will not allow an unauthorized operation.

Comment: Excellent article.  Thank you.  One of it's suggestions is a hybrid approach, where you use the secure cookie to provide the JWT for authentication and use a specific endpoint such as /user/current to provide the authorization information.  As they point out, you need to guard against CSRF attacks with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an `OPTIONS` handler on the server, which returns a list of allowed methods for the current resource and the currently logged in user. For example, let's say you have the following API:

> Fetch user: `GET /user/1`
>
> Modify user: `PATCH /user/1`

**As an administrator**

> Request: `OPTIONS /user/1`
>
> Response: `Allow: GET, PATCH`

**As a user**

> Request: `OPTIONS /user/1`
>
> Response: `Allow: GET`

You could then infer the meaning of the options response in your client app and show/hide actions accordingly.

Resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Allow